# .NET Core: COM delegate throws System.AccessViolationException when trying to call 32-bit dllhost from 64-bit application

Tags: c#, .net-core, com, delegates, 32bit-64bit

I need to pass a delegate function between .NET 6 32.bit COM server and .NET 6 64.bit client to communicate.
I wrote a sample with a 32-bit server, implemented as a C# class in a class library project, hosted by Windows system surrogate and a 64-bit client that calls the server.

Class code:

```
namespace OutOfProcCOM;

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(Contract.Constants.ServerInterface)]  //F586D6F4-AF37-441E-80A6-3D33D977882D
public interface IServer
{
    double Test();

    void TestEvent([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ChangeDelegate d);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(Contract.Constants.ServerInterface)]  //F586D6F4-AF37-441E-80A6-3D33D977882D
public delegate bool ChangeDelegate();


[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(Contract.Constants.ServerClass)]  //"AF080472-F173-4D9D-8BE7-435776617347"
public sealed class DllServer : IServer
{
    public event OnMyEventDelegate OnMyEvent;

    public double Test()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public void TestEvent([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ChangeDelegate d)
    {
       d?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This is how I register it:

> regsvr32.exe
> "DllServer.comhost.dll"

Registry entry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\AppID\{AF080472-F173-4D9D-8BE7-435776617347}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{AF080472-F173-4D9D-8BE7-435776617347}]
"AppID"="{AF080472-F173-4D9D-8BE7-435776617347}"
```

And here is the client:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("OutOfProcCOM.DllServer");
var obj = (IServer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var x = obj.Test();

obj.TestEvent(() => {
   Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
});
```

Execution of *obj.Test()* is working.
Execution of *obj.TestEvent(...)* throws a **System.AccessViolationException**:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Is there someone who can help me? I am going crazy migrating a COM application to .NET Core!

Thank you!

Comment: Did this work with .NET Framework? Or where are you migrating from?

Comment: You can't use a .NET delegate (which will eventually become a simple/raw native pointer) in a cross-apartment call (out-of-process is one case of this). This must use COM interfaces correctly declared with proxy/stub (or using the universal marshaler if you only use automation data types, eg: VARIANT & friends). The most common way of doing this is connection points https://stackoverflow.com/a/66731842/403671

Comment: @PMF: yes, works with .NET Framework and also if i use both client and server compiled in 64-bit

Comment: @SimonMourier: tried but i had an exception: ".NET Core does not support marshalling delegates to the _Delegate interface provided by the .NET Framework COM Type Library. To marshal a delegate as an interface, marshal it as an IDispatch pointer.'" Can you modify my code Above to make it working? I'm using both client and server compiled with .NET 6, no native code involved. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Not sure what you've tried. You can forget completely about delegates. Only use `object` parameters marshaled as IUnknown or IDispatch, eg: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown]`, etc. Read my link of provide a full project somewhere, not pieces of code.